# How to render an image in content-editable field?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, wysiwyg

I am trying to create a Rich Text Editor with `contenteditable` div, using Angular and TypeScript.

I have managed to save image into database(pouchDB) in Base-64-encoded string.

like this in plain text:

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoUlEQVR4Ae2diXdV1RWH+Q9bba1TLa11WO3SLhRBpIBo=">
```

But when i read it from database and try to render on page as image, it is also displaying as above plain text.

- When i read the img data from DB, is there any convenient way to
  transfer it into HTML object?
- And the `img` tag data could be mixed with other Text content, what is the
  general principal to separate them from each other?

Comment: Not enough information here. How are you actually trying to render it in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render it as innerHTML instead of string?

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

not

```
<div>{{ content }}</div>
```